# horizontal div movement based on current time

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-ui

I am generating a table of time based schedules, that run in hour blocks. I need to use this table to move between points based on time. So for example I will have a setLINE that will run from the top to the bottom of the browser. Then I need to pan a div or a table horizontally based on current time in relation to the times on the table. I have no idea where to even start with this, can anyone help me or point me in the correct direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is missing some information, so I'll answer with some assumptions -

1. Decide your dimensions and ratios:
   ie.  Screen dimensions are pixels,  time dimensions are hours, and lets decide the ratio is that each hour is represented by 30 pixels on screen.
2. Decide what time is the left most side of the table,  ie. 12am.
3. So if you want to draw an event from 2am to 3am it would start 60 pixels from the left side (2 hours= 2*30 pixels) and have a width of 30 pixels (one hour long).  Basically you do time-of-event minus the time-of-the-left-side-of-table and the result (in hours) times 30pixels is where you draw the event.
4. If you want to change the "current time" you can change the time of the left most side of the table. Ie. when you want the center of the screen to focus on 9am you can have the left most side of the table set to be 5am.

I hoped that helped.